# Go2 map from one type to another

Tags: go, generics, mapping

In [this example](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/uT-idb0tDyv) of the proposal for Go generics, the `Mapable` type only has a single type parameter.

How can the example be modified to allow mapping from one type to another?

For example, how can I rewrite the Map method to allow mapping from `int` to `float64`?
I tried placing the expression `[Y any]` in various places in the declaration for `Map`, but none passed the syntax checker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky thing I see here is that when you do the mapping operation, you expect that the result will also be a `Mapable`. So, if you map the array of type `T` to array of type `K`, you have to choose what will the result be mappable to. Back to `T`? Or only to itself? Or to a third type? (In this case you'd have to add one more type argument).

First things first, `Mapable` struct would have to accept two type parameters - type of the input array and type of the result array. So it should probably look like this:

```golang
type Mapable[T, K any] struct {
    Arr []T
}
```

Now `Map` function doesn't accept the function `T -> T`, but `T -> K`:

```golang
func (m Mapable[T, K]) Map(fn func(T) K) Mapable[K, K] {
    var newCol []K
    for _, item := range m.Arr {
        newCol = append(newCol, fn(item))
    }
    return NewMapable[K, K](newCol)
}
```

Now, for the simplicity, I chose that the return type was `Mapable[K, K]`, ie. that the result `Mapable` could only be mapped to the same type, but you could choose to return `Mapable[K, T]` so that the `Mapable` could be "mapped back" to the first type.

Anyways, here's the Playground with the new code: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/OxOwaaL16AX

And here's your code next to mine for better visibility of what's changed: https://www.textcompare.org/index.html?id=5f6df344fa7b900017d8d157